# What is the most powerful one handed weapon in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a definitive 'Best Weapon' for each weapon type in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42686/is-there-a-definitive-best-weapon-for-each-weapon-type-in-skyrim)

What is the most powerful one handed weapon in terms of damage in Skyrim?

Answer (score 2):

A daedric sword with fortify one-handed and absorb health is very powerful. Add another 3 items with fortify one-handed and you can get 400+ damage with one sword. Also a sword is much faster then an axe and a mace. also remember to improve it at a grindstone if you have arcane smithing and deadric smithing.

Comment: How can i get that ? Or i should forge it ?

Comment: @Mori: You need to forge it. I didn't come across such a weapon yet.

Answer (score 0):

The Daedric weapons are the 'best' in the game. If you have a set of smithing armor max'd with Fortify Smithing, then you can improve both the deadric weapons you find and craft your own.  If you have enchanting max'd out (and armor that fortifies enchantment) then you can also give even better effects to your daedric weapon than can be found in the wild. It all depends on what you want to do.

Comment: My smithing is 80 ,but I only have "improve magical items" ability,are 'deadric weapons available in normal forgers ?

Comment: @Mori: If you max out the perks for Smithing, yes. For enchanting, you want to max out the center tree perks (go up the 'dual perk' tree)

Answer (score 0):

You can Drop and Improve any weapon in he game,but you can only Create it if you have the respective perk for doing so.

There is no such thing as "better" one handed weapon in the game, it all depends on your playstyle among with the perks you are willing to invest, and the presence or any enchantment.

Swords do less damage,but they hit faster and have critical strike chance perk, with enchantments it will do more damage because of the frequence of the enchantment will hit

Axes do more damage, but they are a slower than swords, and have perks to make your oponent bleed, which can lead you do kill him without having to stay for the finishing move

Maces do great damage, but they are slow as hell, tho they have perks that makes you ignore armor when you hit (reminding that everying in skyrim have armor,even animals,giants, and all sort of creature).

Make your choice and be happy, but, if you have no points in one handed weapon for extra damage, or either have any skills leveled as one handed, your damage will be too low, with any weapon.

Comment: Hmm,bot being a warrior is fun anyway,but the true power is in magic