# what sword has the highest base damage in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a definitive 'Best Weapon' for each weapon type in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42686/is-there-a-definitive-best-weapon-for-each-weapon-type-in-skyrim)

I am about to make the Daedric sword in skyrim and I want to know if it is worth it. I have made a ton of iron daggers in the game to get my smithing level high enough to make the Daedric sword and armor but I don't want to have this weapon when there could be 10 swords that are stronger than it.

Comment: improving a Daedric sword makes it stronger, and since you got the Daedric perk, improving it makes it even more stronger! So yes the Daedric sword is the strongest!