# Which legendary items are more useful than a well-itemized Rare at max level/in Inferno?

Tags: diablo-iii

Legendary items in Diablo 3 max out at level 62. This means that, strictly speaking, a Legendary item in any given slot, will *not* be the best item available in that slot.

As with all things however, there are exceptions. You see, the thing is, there are a few legendaries, like [The Flavor of Time](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-flavor-of-time), which offer unique properties. These are either affixes that are not normally available in that item slot, but which are *highly* desirable, such as +Run Speed, or powerful set bonuses that can offset the reduction in itemization.

Which items are these that I should be keeping an eye out for?

<sub>For an example of the sort of information I'm looking for, see [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42686/is-there-a-definitive-best-weapon-for-each-weapon-type-in-skyrim/42749#42749) about Skyrim.</sub>

Comment: Hard to say that they aren't the BiS since there's no specification as to what "BiS" is in Diablo. BiS for what? DPS? Survivability? Magic Find? Speed?

Comment: @Koviko Strictly speaking, a rare with the same affixes, has *the potential* to be better than a legendary in the same slot in every case, thus, Legendaries are not worth explicitly seeking out in most cases. However, there are exceptions, which is what I'm really asking for.

Comment: I know about String of Ears (up to 20% melee dmg reduction is without a doubt best in slot for barbs right now) and stormshield (which is insanely good, but probably not best in slot), but just two is kinda lame for an answer.

Comment: @heishe Feel free to start a CW with those if nobody comes along to post something more comprehensive.

Comment: @heishe Yeah was gunna say this, String of Ears is godlike for Monk as well as Barb.

Comment: Every legendary is desirable, and each build will focus on a different piece of equipment. This is just a "name every legendary in the game" question

Comment: @Domocus It is decidedly *not* a "name every legendary in the game" question. I am specifically interested only in those legendaries which offer *actual useful* properties (i.e. not Life on Kill), that *can not* be found on a randomly generated item of similar level/slot. That's a relatively manageable list.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz the answer to this question will be out of date as of the point that Blizzard patch legendary stats.

Comment: not only that it'll be out of date in bits and pieces as they tune certain items.  I'm sure the natalya's set will be nerfed soon so I'm not sure if its still worth mentioning

Comment: So now that most legendaries are going to have properties that aren't possible on normal items, what do you want to do with this question?

Answer (score 19):

**Helmets:**
[The Helm of Command](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/the-helm-of-command) These will be the BiS for barbs and most likely monks due to the rolls of %life, % block, res All and Dex/Vit/Str.

[Mempo of Twilight](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/mempo-of-twilight) will be a PvPer helmet due to its high percent of cc reduction, % life, and attack speed.

[Andariel's Visage](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/andariels-visage) is one of the most widely used helmets in the game at the moment. High attack speed and crit chance + chance for a socket, % life, and high base stat.

**Chest:**
[Tyrael's Might](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/tyraels-might) Chest with movement speed (movespeed) increase and damage increase to elites.

[Beckon Sail](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/beckon-sail) Top chestpiece for Demon hunters due to high Increased Attack Speed (IAS) and crit chance increase. Can roll 0-3 sockets for huge Dexterity bonus.

[Tal Rasha's Guardianship](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/tal-rashas-guardianship) IAS on chest and a set bonus of (2) 3% increased fire damage, (3) 3% increased lightning damage, and (4) 3% increased cold damage.

**Pants:**
[Inna's Glory](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-glory) IAS, movespeed, and crit chance.

**Jewelry**:
[Justice Lantern](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/justice-lantern) for extra %block.

[Natalya's Mark](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-mark) IAS + high base stat rolls and use of Set bonus.

[Flavor of Time](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-flavor-of-time) like OP stated IAS, movespeed, and CC reduction on a neck. PvP neck for sure.

[Mara's Kaleidoscope](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/maras-kaleidoscope) decent tank neck with reduction from melee/ranged.

**Off hands:**
[Storm Shield](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/stormshield) for the % reduced damage.

[Ivory Tower](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/ivory-tower) is another decent shield that can be used for its damage reduction and its chance at high % life.

[Black Bone Arrows](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/black-bone-arrows) for % damage against elites will make farming quicker for DH.

[Dead Man's Legacy](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/dead-mans-legacy) is another quiver. This differs from black bone in the fact that it can give % increase to some of DH strongest abilities along with a chance for the highest % attack speed on quiver.

[Uhkapian Serpent](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/uhkapian-serpent) is BiS for WD due to its chance at max off hand damage, % damage against elites and chance on roll to give % damage to certain WD spells.

[The Oculus](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-oculus) like the WD mojo this can give specific spell % increase as well as being able to roll high Int and top damage on a source.

**Belts:**
[String of Ears](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/string-of-ears) for the % melee damage reduction.

**Boots:**
[Boj Anglers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/boj-anglers) Increased attack speed and movespeed with cc reduction. These will be pvp boots in my eyes and can be fitted to any class.

[Zunimassa's Journey](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/zunimassas-journey) Increased attack speed and movespeed.

[Fire Walkers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/fire-walkers) Reduced melee and movespeed.

[Natalya's Soul](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-soul) Reduced melee damage and movespeed.

**Bracers:**
[Lacuni Prowlers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/lacuni-prowlers) These are extremely powerful at the moment for an increase in movespeed to hit that 25% everyone wants and IAS which is a straight damage increase. Even better is these can proc magic properties to make them beneficial to all classes.

**Weapon:**
[The Three Hundredth Spear](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-three-hundredth-spear), [The Gidbinn](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-gidbinn), and [Sunkeeper](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/sun-keeper) all %MF weapons for you and your Companions.

Comment: Did a complete rehaul, hope it helps.

Comment: This is a great start! Thanks! I'm not going to accept this just yet, as there are a handful of others that I'm aware of that are missing from this list -  not going to mention them in hopes that someone will name one I'm not aware of while trying to play the guessing game.

Comment: @Koochi The IAS on these items aren't working right?

Comment: @Cyril Pangilinan At the moment items that say "Attack speed increased by #" are working but those that say "Increase attack speed by #" are NOT working properly.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a few more to the list:

**Bul Kathos's Wedding Band**: Guaranteed (high for rings) life on hit, % life, strength, and 2 random magic affixes.  Great to have for barbs and tanks.

**Band of Hollow Whispers**: Great tanky ring with LoH, resist all, and vitality.

**Beckon Sail**: Favored armor of DH(3 socket ones can sell for enormous amounts of gold), has no useless base mods.

**Ouroboros**: Guarenteed life on hit again, just like Bul Kathos, handy for tanks.

**Tal Rasha's Guardianship**: IAS on chest piece, resist all, magic find

Comment: tal rasha's and beckon sail are only ones i can add to list. the OP wants properties that arent normally on rings according to post, LoH can be found on rings already.

Comment: @Koochi well he asked which ones are still useful at max level/inferno and the ones I listed are all commonly used in tank builds for inferno as LoH is huge there

Answer (score 1):

Note: After 1.0.3, the best way to maximise your dps is to get critical hit chance/damage everywhere you can.

Get critical hit chance on: (the percentage is a good target to have)

- off hand 8%
- gloves 8%
- rings 4.5%
- amulet 8%
- bracers 4%
- helm 4%

Get critical damage on:

- Weapon (socket + base critical hit damage). 120-150%
- gloves 40%
- amulet 60%
- rings 30%

My point is that you will have to get gloves, rings and amulet with both high crit chance and high crit damage. And there is almost no legendary that satisfies this criteria.

---

The lists presented here are very incomplete. I will add some dps items from the top of my head:

- Blackthorne set, especially the blackthorne's medal

[image]

- screaming chain

[image]

- skull grasp

[image]

- sage seekers

[image]

- fire walkers

[image]

- storm crow

[image]

Comment: I agree! Feel free to expand upon or improve them. Also, a bit more detail than a list of item names (what about it is special?) would be handy.